# Test ApolloClient API with Jest in Vue3 (Composition API)

Tags: jestjs, graphql, apollo-client, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using `Vue3 (typescript)` with `Composition API` for my application. I am using `ApolloClient` `grapghql` for API calls. I have created a separate service file for API calls. (PFB files)

**Service file**

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client/core"
import { gql } from "@apollo/client/core"
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_GRAPHQL_URI,
    fetch
})

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})

export const getAplloAPIdata = async  (reqQuery: any) => {
    const query = gql `${reqQuery}`
    try {
        return await apolloClient.query({ query })
    }catch {
        console.log('API error')
    }
}
```

**Home.vue**

```js
setup() {
    const threatList = ref([])
    const threat = ref(null)

    // get all threats
    const getThreats = async () => {
        const getThreatsQuery = `
            query {
                threats {
                    short_description
                    threat_level
                }
            }
        `

        try {
            const result = await getAplloAPIdata(getThreatsQuery)
            if (result) {
                threatList.value = result.data.threats
            }
        } catch {
            console.log('Error receiving threats data')
        }
    }
```

Can you please tell me how can I write test cases to mock this API in jest? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) `getAplloAPIdata` to return mock data, and verify that data in your test. The key is to make sure the mock path is the same as that imported in your component:

```js
// Home.vue
import { getAplloAPIdata } from '@/service'
/*...*/

// Home.spec.js
jest.mock('@/service', () => {
  return {
    getAplloAPIdata: () => ({
      data: {
        threats: [{ id: 123456 }]
      }
    })
  }
})

describe('Home.vue', () => {
  it('gets threats', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Home)
    await wrapper.vm.getThreats()
    expect(wrapper.vm.threatList).toContainEqual({ id: 123456 })
  })
})
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue3-jest-mock-demo)